# Time Complexity Review

Tags: time, big-o, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity for the following code snippet?

```
int[][] A = new int [n][];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) // i is a multiple of 2
        A[i] = new int [n];
    else
        A[i] = new int [1];
}

for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<A[i].length; j++)
        sum = sum + A[i][j];
```

I understand the first for loop loops n times, then, there will be `n/2` rows of of matrix of at length n, and `n/2` of at length 1.  Would the total time be `n^2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the complexity will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

---

**How?**

- Half of the times (i.e. n/2 times), you will iterate through n elements = (n/2) * n = n<sup>2</sup>/2.
- Half of the times (again, n/2 times), you will have only one element to iterate over = (n/2) * 1 = n/2.
- Therefore, overall complexity = O(n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/2) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for Confirming:)

Comment: Good explanation regarding to big-O :)

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly let's decide with terminology. For example, let's put that every single operation will be to equal to `1`. Let's take your code (just to be consistent - we will call this method) and go line by line.

```
int[][] A = new int [n][];
```

this will be equal to `1`.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

Here we have loop and in worst case it will be `n`.

```
    if (i % 2 == 0) // 1
        A[i] = new int [n]; // 1
    else
        A[i] = new int [1]; // 1
}
```

Above operation could be counted as `1` each.

```
for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
```

Loop is equal to `n`-elements.

```
    for (int j=0; j<A[i].length; j++)
```

Inner loop is the same `n`.

```
        sum = sum + A[i][j];
```

Again this will be equal to `1`.

Inner loops are **multiplied** so you are correct, but take into account that this will be exactly big-O notation O(n<sup>2</sup>).